# Does Textmate have a shortcut for hash? i.e. => it's such a pain to type!

Tags: ruby, textmate

1. Does textmate have a shortcut for hash? i.e. =>  it's such a pain to type!
2. What about smart snippets where you can create a code block with replacement variables, and it cycles through the replacement variables to quickly modify the code template?

Any good links on using textmate with rails to code faster? tips/tricks etc.

Comment: This should be tagged ruby, not ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Two keypresses are hard to type? You'll waste two key presses typing the `<CTRL>+L` shortcut. Jeez, kids these days... back in my day we edited with mud tablets and sticks. NOW GET OFF MY LAWN! :-)

Comment: Mud tablets and sticks? Luxury! We had to scratch our code into rocks with our finger nails in a snow storm while going uphill both ways 28 hours a day down at the mill!

Comment: @Greg: By that logic, isn't `=>` three keypresses: `=` then `<Shift>+.`?

Comment: I read the question. I read the answers. I puzzled for several minutes. And finally I realised that you weren't asking about the hash key (`#`), but about the syntax `=>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have an alternative hash syntax in Ruby 1.9:

```
  # old way that still works in Ruby 1.9
  my_hash = { :a => 'apple', :b => 'banana' }

  # new way
  my_hash = { a: 'apple', b: 'banana' }
```

Since this is being voted up, I'm adding Josiah Kiehl's comment

> Note that you can't do anything but
>   symbol keys with this method. ie:
>   {someobject => 'value', 'string' =>
>   'value', 123 => 'value'}

Comment: Wow this is the first I've heard of this, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Note that you can't do anything but symbol keys with this method.  ie: `{someobject => 'value', 'string' => 'value', 123 => 'value'}`  That said, I use the new syntax whenever I can as I very much prefer it.

Answer (score 4):

1) Use crtl + L

2) Look under the Bundles > Ruby or Bundles > Ruby on Rails menus. There's all sorts of stuff there.